# Return a dict containing the first N list entries for each key from a dict of lists

Tags: python, dictionary

Consider the following dictionary of lists, d:

```
{
'ra': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
'decl': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
'source_id': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
'priority': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
}
```

I would like to return a dictionary containing <= the first N values in the list for every dictionary key. Hence if `N = 4`, it should return

```
{
'ra': [0, 1, 2, 3],
'decl': [0, 1, 2, 3],
'source_id': [0, 1, 2, 3],
'priority': [0, 1, 2, 3],
}
```

or if the list is shorter than 4 entries, to return the full list. A bit like `.head(N)` works for data frames.

I can convert the dictionary to a data frame, perform the `.head(N)` operation and convert it back to a dict, but it seems like there must be an easier/more Pythonic way to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd go for something using dict comprehension

```
lessen = {
'ra': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
'decl': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
'source_id': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
'priority': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
}
limit = 4
new = {k:v[:limit] for k,v in lessen.items()}
```

output

```
{'ra': [0, 1, 2, 3], 'decl': [0, 1, 2, 3], 'source_id': [0, 1, 2, 3], 'priority': [0, 1, 2, 3]}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly easy to do with a simple `for` loop:

```
N = 4
for key in thedata:
    thedata[key] = thedata[key][:N]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
dct = {
    'ra': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    'decl': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    'source_id': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    'priority': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
}

new_dct = {key: values[0:4] for key, values in dct.items()}
print(new_dct)
```